# why Laravel controller doesn't show the zero leading when search from number starts with 0

Tags: laravel, leading-zero

I'm using laravel and I can create a record with barcode = 069, or barcode = 006, however when I
Click the search button, it shows 69 in the form, below view, controller...etc, please I need help:

**HTML where i enter value to search:**

```xml
<div class="container my-container">
  <div class="lead text-center font">
    <h3><strong><u> Search Form</u></h3></strong>
  </div>
  <form action="{{ route('store.show')}}" method="GET">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" required name="name" placeholder="Scan Barcod">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit"  value="serach">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

**Controller:** for the same view

```
public function show()
{
    $saved_barcode= request('name');
    $searchbyfield = store::find($saved_barcode);

    if ($searchbyfield) {
        return view('store.show', ['store'=> $searchbyfield]);
    }

    return redirect('store/create')->with('missing', 'Item not Found');
}
```

**HTML where show the search result**

```xml
<form action= "{{ route('store.editbarcode',$store -> barcode) }}"  method="GET">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <strong>Asset ID </strong></strong>
      <span style="color: red">*</span>
    </span>
    <input disabled  type="text" class="form-control" required id="barcode" name="barcode" value="{{ $store -> barcode }}">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" >
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: What's your database table structure?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Store has barcode as a string, you could pass the search input as a string instead of int, cuase when you pass it to **->find()** it gets casted as int
What you can do is in your **controller**:

```
public function show()
{
         $saved_barcode= request('name');
         $searchbyfield = store::where('barcode', $saved_barcode)->first();
         if ($searchbyfield) {
            return view('store.show', ['store'=> $searchbyfield]);
         }
         return redirect('store/create')->with('missing', 'Item not Found');
}
```

**EDIT**

After reading what you said, perhaps you would wanna set this value in your Store model:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'barcode';
public $incrementing = false;
protected $keyType = 'string';
```

Comment: Sorry but it did not, I have an issue what the retrieval process, it shows the wrong info, i.e: when I enter 069 which is saved the same in MySql, it shows \ retrieve 69

Comment: It works if I remove "protected $primaryKey = 'barcode'; " from the below Model, however, I can not search ID, i need to search by barcode field which is varchar(255):
so it has nothing to do with HTML or CSS, but the controller and the way it retrieves the data from SQL! 

class store extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'store';
    protected $primaryKey = 'barcode'; 
 }

So can someone help please as i tried all the above senarios but it did not work

Comment: @Edi, please check the edit I made, especially the $keyType

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably because you are saving barcode value in integer type column.

To allow your database engine store leading zeros, you should change the column type to varchar or string as in Laravel. It will solve your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the reason, the barcode type is (varchar(255)) and when the number is saved in MySQL table, it shows 069, but when I retrieve the data it comes as 69 and is being displayed in my web form as 69

Comment: try this in your form:
    <input disabled  type="text" class="form-control" required id="barcode" name="barcode" value="{{ (string) $store -> barcode }}">

Comment: It did not work, i have replaced it with value="{{ (string) $store -> barcode }}", but still when i search for 069, it return 69 in the form, this is really weird!!!

Can someone help me plezzzz